# SQL Server Express won't let me install to alternate directory

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-express

As per the title, when I download the SQL Server Express SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe and run it I get asked for where I want to install it. I specify a place on my D drive with the basic installation, I do this because my C is a small SSD and I just need an express server to test stuff on my local machine so it does not need to be especially performant. But at the end of the installation process I get the error message

```
Exit code (Decimal)
-2054422498
Exit message
The specified directory, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\", for the INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter is not valid because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory. Specify a directory that is not compressed.
```

My OS is Windows-10 newest edition.

Comment: Why did you mark that folder as compressed? It's trying to install the shared file into that directory. I'm not sure how the installer looks but if you have a feature selection you might be able to change the directory for each individual feature.

Comment: I marked that folder as compressed because I want to compress contents on that drive that is very small, this is why I want to install on a different non-compressed drive. It allows me to select another drive for installation but it comes with a message that it could not install to this one, which is problematic.

Comment: Is there a feature selection or not? If there is, did you make sure to change the drive for every Feature? If there is no feature selection you're probably out of luck or would have to resort to some kind of hack. You could e.g. use a link to redirect the folder. Otherwise you could disable the compression for that folder, install an reenable. Though it's likely that there is a reason it's aborting the installation in that fashion.